# Can Spring Boot and Vert.x be mixed into one artifact / deployment?

Tags: spring-boot, vert.x

Suppose I have a Spring Boot application: can I use both, a `@RestController` and Vert.x `Router` to define APIs in the same application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! Assuming you are using Vert.x `3.3.x`, have a look [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples/springboot-example).

Basically you need a Spring component with your route definition(s), and be able to inject it into `Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle` when the application starts. I'm not sure if you can mix end-point definition(s) with the same "root context(s)" though.

In any case, Spring Boot and Vert.x plays well together (so far). There are some more examples also [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I had try it but when start it deploy two server are Vertx server and Spring boot. I want it start into one port like 8080 also use Route and Rest controller. Can I do that?

Comment: Both can't use the same port, one artifact will be bound while the other one will fail. Basically they both start a "server" and hence, need a `port` on its own. You need different ports for each. Spring Boot can use Tomcat, Undertow, etc; Vert.x uses Netty.

Comment: Tks, I will try other ways.